# How to decode special characters with Apache Tika

Tags: java, parsing, ms-word, apache-poi, apache-tika

I'm using **Apache Tika** to parse some MS Word documents to HTML (String). Problem is that some documents contains special characters (e.g. Mathematical Operators). Is any way how to solve it? Thank you for help.

**Input:**
[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Source Code**

```
SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler handler = null;

try {
  handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
   logger.warn(String.format("SAX Processing is not available: ", e));
   return;
}

handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
handler.setResult(new StreamResult(output)); // StringWriter output
```

Comment: Have you tried using the same font to display the HTML as Microsoft uses in Office when encoding the text with non-standard glyphs?

Comment: Yes, in Office doc is common font Arial.